# How to get clicked item in directive inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in list">
    <td>{{item.name}}</td> 
    <td><button ng-click="remove" is-disabled>Delete!</button></td>
</tr>
```

And directive `isDisabled` with

```
return {
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs)
        {
           // get clicked row here 
        }
};
```

How can I get `item` inside this directive? `$scope.list` - list of items
I found that I can use `$index` in `ng-repeat`, is it correct way? Is there other solutions?

Comment: Where is the `isDeleted` directive?

Comment: Sorry, it have been a typo, updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could access the current item by accessing the parent scope like this:

```
scope.$parent.item
```

But it's not advisable as it will create a **tight coupling** in code and a hard-coded property named **item**.

Try creating your directive like this:

```
app.directive("isDisabled", function() {
  return {
    scope:{
      item:"="
    },
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
        console.log(scope.item);
    }
  };
});
```

and pass in the item:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in list">
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td>
        <button ng-click="remove" is-disabled item="item">Delete!</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/u68d2uZQWRtiXTnOZjE9?p=catalogue)